# Cross-browser triangle div with full height/width

Tags: animation, html, rotation, transform

Is there any way to make something as shows on img below
http://img338.imageshack.us/img338/6953/rotanim1.gif

two full height div and 50% width. on center divs are some radius on border. Text are overlayed on each divs. I want to make jquery animated trick when i click on link 1 th whole right white side goes on left:0px. The same about black left side - then everything goes full right.

I try to make some -webkit-transform: (XXdeg) but then the whole text inside div is rotated too. I try with css border trick but i don't think that's a good idea.

Any solutions about this case?
Sorry for my english. Hope you understand my thinking :)

Comment: The easiest solution would probably be canvas or svg (with other html elements over it if needed).

Answer (score 0):

There are many tricks enabling the use of oblique shapes in css (see for example [this](http://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/)).

Thus you probably can build a solution doing a similar effect using css+js but the truth is that this will be hard to maintain and won't support slight evolution.

In your case I suggest you use [SVG](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/SVG) or a [canvas](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Canvas). You may control both kind of solutions easily and accurately with javascript. And you may use z-index to display other html/css elements over it if needed.